# C# .NET - Winforms - Create a table with a header row and header column

Tags: datagrid

I am new to C# but I will try to be as specific as possible.

Using Windows Form, I am looking to create a table that has:

- 10 columns and 10 rows
- A header row and a header column with labels
  for each row and column (that never change)
- I want to be able to access each cell of that table
- I do not want to add lines and columns using code (topic covered in several posts) but rather to create my fixed form that I will then populate using code.

Two possibilities seem to be quite good:

- TableLayoutPanel: but can we access each cell using code? I am not sure.
- DataGridView seems the best choice; but it seems that a line is added when we add data to the first line (and so on). In addition, I did not manage to add a label for each row.

Could anyone help me please?
Thank you very much